# center position the image

Tags: html, css, center

I want the position of image to be center.I used the `center` tag & text-align but its not working.Please help

**CSS:**

```
#indtrans
{
    position :fixed;
    display:block;
    background-color : none;
    top: 2px; 
    text-align:center;
    padding-left:130px;
}
```

**html:**

```
 <center><div  id="indtrans"><img src="indeximg.png"></img></div></center>
```

Comment: Center to the body or to the div?

Comment: I think more context is needed to say anything, like any div in which this image is not only center tag and `indtrans`.

Comment: Its position is fixed. I want it to be positioned at the top of the screen and aligned center.

Comment: position:fixed does work ,the only problem is the alignment of the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
#indtrans
 {
   display: block;
   left: 50%;
   position: fixed;
   top: 2px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

if you give the div a set width, then you should be able to set a margin: 0 auto; which would center it.

Answer (score 0):

Add `width:100%`

Change css like this

```
    #indtrans{
    position :fixed;
    display:block; width:100%;
    background-color : none;
    top: 2px; 
    text-align:center;
    padding-left:130px;
}​
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/RbbAx/6/)**

Comment: i want the position:fixed;. I tried the above text-align works with position:relative.

Answer (score -1):

Because you are positioning your `#indtrans` DIV with position fixed, you will need to be more specific in your alignment. Simply using `margin: 0 auto;` will not work.

Instead try this. The margin left will need to be a minus of 50% of the total width of your element.

```
#indtrans
{
    position :fixed;
    display:block;
    background-color : none;
    top: 2px; 
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: (-50% of total width);
    text-align:center;
    padding-left:130px;
}
```